# Can I load external layouts as standard layouts in Spyder?

Tags: python, layout, ide, spyder

Currently I save the layouts in "View/Window layouts/Save current layout" all right.  Have how to save the layouts to an external file or otherwise and load them as the
"SpyderLayout, HorizontalSplitLayout, VerticalSplitLayout, RLayout,MatlabLayout " ?

Our team works with 3 different layouts. I'm trying to save these 3 layouts as default, to be loaded when installing the plugin.

Comment: I'm trying to do this because our team is reasonably great and everyone uses the plugin.

Comment: Just in case, linking the related issue created in the Spyder repository: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17529